Neo4j endless running spatial query
I have a neo4j DB that has two separate nodes types, one for blasthole data and one for a geological block model. It took a serious effort from my side to import data for those nodes to populate from a csv but I was able to achieve this with a CALL method. The block model has around 3 million nodes with maybe 12 properties and the blasthole sample node has around 30k. I am struggling to come up with an efficient query to create a spatial relationship that stores a calculated distance.
I was able to run the following query.
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (b:BlastholeSamples) RETURN b" LIMIT 100,
  "WITH b
   MATCH (g:GeologicalBlock)
   WHERE g.location.x >= b.location.x - 100 AND g.location.x <= b.location.x + 100
   AND g.location.y >= b.location.y - 100 AND g.location.y <= b.location.y + 100
   AND point.distance(b.location, g.location) <= 100  
   AND abs(b.midZ_D - g.ELEV) < 0.5  
   WITH b, g, point.distance(b.location, g.location) AS distance  
   CREATE (b)-[r:LOCATED_IN {distance: distance}]->(g)", 
  {batchSize: 50, iterateList: true}
);

With the intent to create a bounding box around the blasthole sample for relationship evaluation. If geological block points are in the box create a relationship and store the distance.
Prior to this query I did create indexs based on the x,y,z values and create a location property for cartesian.
The query cannot be optimal as it ran for over 18 hours before I terminated it. This seems way too long.
It did seem to work and generate a results for some of the nodes, which is awesome.
Bloom Image
Please any help to optimize or provide some tip that I may have missed? I am super new at neo4j and cypher.

I assume you created a POINT index for GeologicalBlock.location. A POINT index is only used by some spatial functions (see Supported predicates table at the link). So, you should: (1) store 3D points (if you do not already do so), and (2) use point.withinBBox() to pre-filter the points.
For example, assuming that BlastholeSamples.location and GeologicalBlock.location are stored as 'cartesian-3D' points, something like this may work for you:
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (b:BlastholeSamples) RETURN b.location AS loc LIMIT 100",
  "MATCH (g:GeologicalBlock)
   WHERE point.withinBBox(g.location,
     point({x: loc.x-100, y: loc.y-100, z: loc.z-100}),
     point({x: loc.x+100, y: loc.y+100, z: loc.z+100}))
   AND point.distance(loc, g.location) <= 100
   CREATE (b)-[:LOCATED_IN {distance: point.distance(loc, g.location)}]->(g)", 
  {batchSize: 50}
);

Below is an alternative query that does the more expensive point.distance calculation just once. The relatively cheap point.withinBBox calculation is still done first (during the MATCH) to filter out most of the inappropriate points.
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (b:BlastholeSamples) RETURN b.location AS loc LIMIT 100",
  "MATCH (g:GeologicalBlock)
   WHERE point.withinBBox(g.location,
     point({x: loc.x-100, y: loc.y-100, z: loc.z-100}),
     point({x: loc.x+100, y: loc.y+100, z: loc.z+100}))
   WITH b, g, point.distance(loc, g.location) AS dist
   WHERE dist <= 100
   CREATE (b)-[:LOCATED_IN {distance: dist}]->(g)", 
  {batchSize: 50}
);


Thanks @cybersam.
I had created a regular index instead of a point index. Your suggestions helped the query was much faster. 364149 ms
However, I also reimported only the geological blocks that I needed.  I will try with the full dataset. Cheers!

Hmm. 6 minutes is slow for just 100 locs; I guess you have a lot of GeologicalBlocks. I have added an alternative solution to my answer. It does the point.distance calculation just once. It may be faster.
